# Convert javascript animation to css class for bootstrap modal popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

I have bootstrap modal popup in my existing project (Which was implemented by other developer ) Where client has mentioned specific behaviour for opening modal popup using following js code ( we are not using default bootstrap modal methods to open / close dialog. )

```
$(dialog).css('top', '-1000px').show().animate({ top: '-1px' }, {
            duration: 1100, easing: 'easeInOutBack', complete: function () { 
            // No need of this
            }
        });
```

Due to this I am facing many issue and i have to manage all stuff manuly like overlay ,close etc.

What I found at http://hawkee.com/snippet/16154/ that for using custom behaviour of opening modal popup I dont need this custom js code but I can achieve this by pure css only. As per this site I just need to change **.modal.fade** and **.modal.fade.in** classes;

As I am not that much expert at animation I need some guidance how I can convert this js written effect to css only.

After some R&D I found may be I can use this http://easings.net/#easeInOutBack But not sure.

I have achieved this till now :

[**http://codepen.io/kaushikthanki/pen/kXGqjo**](http://codepen.io/kaushikthanki/pen/kXGqjo)

Answer (score 0):

Kaushik,

I changed the style based on hawkee example that you shared. Hope it will work as you expected.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  top: -1000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1100ms ease-in-out;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
  top: -1px
}
```

Comment: thx for your help. I have achieved so far but still need some improvements 

http://codepen.io/kaushikthanki/pen/xOXZmK

Comment: Look fantastic. I also re-produce Bootstrap modal, if you wanna try. http://codepen.io/trungk18/pen/dXVmEE

Comment: Really impressive,now only two thing missing for my requirement.
1. that easeinoutback effect 
2. Just need to stick at top for modal when it's opens. 

can we achieve that ?

Comment: Thanki, I didn't really get what you mean for 2 others req :D

Comment: For ur shared ref does not have the easeInOutBack transition and second thing I wanted to keep modal popup position which stick to top of document.

Comment: Kaushik, how is this going ? I have just back from my holiday

Comment: @trugk no luck yet